# jQuery Ajax: VM845:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a small issue. My website has been working for few month without an issue. Now suddenly I get 2 errors in my chrome browser:

> VM845:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

and the 2nd error is a `404` for `/engine_prodJSON.php` which is used in one of my ajax requests. So yeah, I have managed to track the error to my `$.ajax` function which is:

```
var urlFetch = "/content/engine/engine_prodJSON.php";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlFetch,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function(resp){
        prodArr = resp;
        $('.search').prop('disabled', false);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        console.log(err.Message);
    }
});
```

I would like to note that, to my knowledge, neither that function, nor the `engine_prodJSON.php` has been moved/changed in any way. I have triple checked via FTP that the file is in fact in the correct folder. I have checked the file permissions which are set up as 644.

I have been wondering if it could be hosting's fault as it has started causing issues approx. 2 hours ago. I'm out of ideas how can I fix it.

Thanks

Comment: which line of code you got the error ?

Comment: 404 not found error points at `$.ajax`. and the Unexpected token error points at `var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");`

Comment: @t.niese any idea why it would return 404 error even though the file is in the correct location ?

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab of Chrome debugger to see what your request is returning ? .. (press F12 to open debugger)

Comment: You need to debug the 404 on the server. If you type the URL in the browser what do you see?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nothing, it forwards me back to the main page. I guess the forwarding has something to do with the .htaccess file which hasn't been touched in like 2 years

Comment: I get: 302 Moved Temporarily for `engine_prodJSON.php` file from chrome response.

Comment: There's your problem. Any request which doesn't return a `200 OK` response goes to the `error` handler in `$.ajax`. You probably need to look at your URL routing scheme to allow this request through.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not sure how to do that tbh. Is it possible that my hosting company does something - given that the file has been working for last few months till today ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Everything that is different to `2xx` or `3xx` will result in the error callback. But so `302` alone won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it,

thanks to @t.niese & @RoryMcCrossan I managed to find where the error has been occurring.

Chrome showed me error 302 Moved Temporarily on an ajax call to `engine_prodJSON.php` file. Which redirected the call to `index.php` that caused the response to be in HTML so the first sign has been `<` which had given me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

I did temporarily rename my `.htaccess` file which fixed my call response to `200 OK`. After that I restored my `.htaccess` file to its previous state and it's still `200 OK`. Seems weird to me that it works now even though I haven't changed anything.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Because the request to `/engine_prodJSON.php` results into a `404` error your the return data is most likely `html`. As of that the *parsing* of this data using `eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");` will fail, because a `<`  is an unexpected token in javascript.

In your error callback you should not add an `eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");`.

Why you get the 404 cannot be sayed without looking on your server. You need to check that in the server logs.

Comment: any idea why it would return 404 error even though the file is in the correct location ?

Comment: @TomaszGolinski or use the Chrome debugger (F12 and network tab) to se exactly what is returned...

Comment: @TomaszGolinski that can have various reasons. Only the logs on the server can tell you why.

Comment: @t.niese where can I find logs on the server? I have just a normal shared hosting with cPanel.

Comment: @TomaszGolinski thats something you need ask you hoster.

Comment: @t.niese Chrome gives me 302 Moved Temporarily for the `engine_prodJSON.php` file

Comment: @TomaszGolinski Maybe you are using a cms that was updated, or some other server rules that changes. Rename the file `engine_prodJSON.php`  and check if you still get the redirect. If yes then either the hoster or you changed something.

Comment: @t.niese I have changed the name and moved it outside the engine folder, still same error... I will just wait till tomorrow and see if it gets fixed. if not then I will dig deeper into it. Thanks for the help though ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check few things:

- Case sensitivity of folder and file names
- File path with respect to the location where the javascript file is referenced
- Is your server still running?